# Should there be a [minecraft-nbt] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft

I've gotten in a dispute over correct tagging of the question [Adding custom structure to replace ancient_city_center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/398117/adding-custom-structure-to-replace-ancient-city-center), in which the creator is adding [minecraft-nbt](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-nbt) and I think it's unnecessary and am removing it.

So, what are your thoughts on whether this tag should exist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

[minecraft-data-packs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-data-packs) has only 105 questions, so there's little need to split it further. Furthermore, as a general principle creating new tags should not be done as a vanity project for one's own question (except when it's for a game no one else has asked about), but instead only if there's a substantial body of existing questions that merit the tag, of which no evidence has been shown.

Comment: I agree. I've rejected the [tag:minecraft-nbt] [tag wiki excerpt suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/319167) for the same reason.

Comment: As somebody who isn't into Minecraft, would you mind summarizing how `minecraft-data-packs` and `minecraft-nbt` are similar enough to be encapsulated within the same tag?

Comment: The tag wiki excerpt suggested for the new tag was "For questions about using NBT data to replace structures, usually in datapacks". Thus the creator acknowledges it is an attempted subtag of [tag:minecraft-data-packs], which IMO is not large enough to need diffusing further.